# How to use ilike for phone number filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi im fetching the user input and displaying the records that matches the condition, my query will look like

```rb
customers = customers.where('customers.contact_num ilike :search', {search: "%#{options[:search_contact]}%"})
```

here in db the contact number is stored in string with the format (091)-234-5678 like that

on while searching the user on basis of contact number if i search like this

091 it filters the number correctly, but while searching like 0912,  it doesn't display record due to the braces, so how to modify the query to neglect the ) and - while searching..
As im new to the domain please help me out

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to convert the phone numbers in the database to e164 format? Possibly using phonelib? You'd have to clean up the existing data, clean up incoming new data, and format the numbers in views but your search would become easy (and it would be easier down the road to interact with phone number based services).

Comment: Please don't abuse the version tags - they are not ornaments and won't get your question any additional attention. The version tag should only be used to provide context that your question is a about a specific version of rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove all non-digit chars from the search - something like below?

`customers = customers.where("REGEXP_REPLACE(customers.contact_num,'[^[:digit:]]','','g') ilike :search", {search: "%#{options[:search_contact]}%"})`

Comment: what will be the value of digit, should we mention any index on that? as im a beginner can u elaborate the query if possible, thanks -jegan @obiruby

Comment: No changes necessary - you should be able to copy / paste the code snippet and (hopefully) it will just work. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query is hard. Let's not do that.

Instead right a quick script to transforms your numbers into
1112223333 form. No formatting at all. Something like:

```rb
require 'set';
phone = "(234)-333-2323"
numbers = Set.new(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"])
output = phone.chars().select{|n| numbers.include?(n)}.join("")
puts output
=> "2343332323"
```

Then write a little function to transform them into display form for use in the views.

This will make your query work as is.